# What is the reason that paragraph return symbols slow Excel VBA program?

Tags: vba, performance, excel, paragraph

When my programs form reports from data files which have large massive of text, often programs execution become very slow. I detected the reason – paragraph marks. After they are removed from text blocks in data files cells, from where data are uploaded, the programs execution speeds become normal again. What is the reason that paragraph return symbols slow Excel VBA program? Is the only way to go around this problem to remove paragraph marks?

More than year ago I encountered with the problem that one of my program start to work very slowly. I spent two days and didn’t find any information which was able to help me. The reason I found when started analyze data which user used in program execution. In these data were text blocks, I copied the text into Word and selected in Home type Paragraph section selected Show paragraph mark. In this text I found paragraph marks. I removed them from data. As this text from data files program used to form reports which has near million rows the speed became normal. So I found solution, but wasted 2 days on it. I be very thankful if I would be able to find information about it at this moment. With this problem I encountered time to time and as I have experience I am able to solve it, but I until now don’t know the reason and is another way to overcome this problem. My question is about it. If you have an answer I be very thankful.

Comment: probably not. depends on your code.

Comment: Question is too broad without slow code?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem from the information you have provided. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As I can’t shortly (in bound of a comment) answer to 2 comments above I expended my question.

Comment: There is no specific reason why the presence of a line feed character in a cell would slow down a generic piece of VBA code.  It is more likely that the presence of a line feed character might slow down your specific VBA code.  (I can think of some code situations which might mean you were accidentally processing trillions of steps instead of just millions of steps.)  But without seeing the code that was being affected, it is really impossible to give an answer, only guesses.